# Android In-App Billing Error InvalidKeySpecException

Tags: android, runtime-error, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement the In-App Purchase using the wrapper of Trivial Gas tutorial. After completion of successful purchase The app crashed, since then the app is getting crashed at the beginning.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long
at com.nightowl.memory.Security.generatePublicKey(Security.java:85)
at com.nightowl.memory.Security.verifyPurchase(Security.java:65)
at com.nightowl.memory.IabHelper.queryPurchases(IabHelper.java:875)
at com.nightowl.memory.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:550)
at com.nightowl.memory.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:528)
at com.nightowl.memory.IabHelper$2.run(IabHelper.java:623)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKey.getPublicKey(OpenSSLKey.java:101)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.java:47)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:171)
at com.nightowl.memory.Security.generatePublicKey(Security.java:80)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.d2i_PUBKEY(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKey.getPublicKey(OpenSSLKey.java:99)
... 9 more
```

I have used the following code to call it:

```
    String base64EncodedPublicKey;
            base64EncodedPublicKey= String.valueOf(R.string.myPubKey);
            additionalSkuList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
                {
                    if(i==0&&j>1)
                        break;
                    additionalSkuList.add(id[i][j]);
                }
            }
            mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
            mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                    Log.d("main", "m here");
                    if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                        // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                        Log.d("main", "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
                    }
                    // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
                    isIAB = true;

                    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList, mQueryFinishedListener);
                    Log.d("main", "" + isIAB + " " + isLoad);
                }
            });


IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener
            mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory)
        {
            Log.d("main", "m here too");
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // handle error
                return;
            }
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
                {
                    if(i==0&&j>1)
                        break;
                    price[i][j]=inventory.getSkuDetails(id[i][j]).getPrice();
                }
            }
            isLoad=true;
            data.setPrice(price);
            data.setDataLoad(true);
            // update the UI
        }
    };

    public void onPurchaseCall()
    {
        int loc[] = data.getItem();
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, id[loc[0]][loc[1]], 100*loc[0]+loc[1],mPurchaseFinishedListener, id[loc[0]][loc[1]]);
    }
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
            = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase)
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.d("main", "Error purchasing: " + result);
                return;
            }
            else if (purchase.getSku().equals(id[0][0])) {
                data.setNoads(1);
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                data.setNotificationState(1);
                data.setNoOfnotifications(2);
                data.setNotificationMsg(0, "Purchase Complete");
                data.setNotificationMsg(1, PurchaseMsg[0]);
                // consume the gas and update the UI
            }


        }
    };
```

Can anyone help me to solve it?  What I guessed from the log is that something problem with the Public Key I provide. But the first time it worked (It was working till I initiated a successful purchase). And I was also getting the price list of all my in-app products.

I tried to test the purchase with a testing account. On successful completion of the purchase this error came and since then the app is not running for that account.

Comment: The Security.generatePublicKey is giving error. If I comment it out and send true forcefully from verifyPurchase function then the code it running properly. Any Idea why this is happening ? I am defining the pubkey as a String (I didn't encode or decode he key myself (which I found as not to do in a solution to a similar problem )). But still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? I'm getting this error from time to time with 1 star rate for my app. This bug makes me crazy *(

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `String.valueOf(R.string.myPubKey)`, it will give you a wrong value.  Instead use `getResources().getString(R.string.myPubKey_data))` to get your public key string.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is old, but i write answer for anyone will have this problem.
The problem is from public key length. It's not valid and is longer than it should be. Make sure you entered it correctly.